# How can I change the width of a QMainWindow separator without it affecting the QDockWidget

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qmainwindow

I have a QDockWidget which has been added to a QMainWindow.  I set the sizeHint of the DocWidget to be 260px and its the size that I want it to be because nothing else is offering up a size.

However now I want to increase the width of the DockWidget - QMainWindow separator.  The only way I have found of doing this is via a StyleSheet:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmainwindow

However when I do this the DockWidget shrinks to < 100px and becomes unusable.  You cannot force the QDockWidget to a certain size and its inheriting the MainWindows stylesheet.

I also cannot get any other handle on the QMainWindow::separator.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems with QPushButtons, when rendering with stylesheets they has decreased to minimum possible size. 
With them i cured that trouble by setting minimum size to needed. Maybe same solution will work for you...

Answer (score 2):

you can use such code:

```
setStyleSheet("QMainWindow::separator {width: 20px}");
```